# Comprehending Java's HashMap in Javascript as a JSON object

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, json, http

I have an application where a Java HashMap is sent over via HTTP protocol, and I have to comprehend that HashMap object in Javascript before appending that JSON object to MySQL database.

I have tried multiple approaches such as

1. Converting HashMap to String in Java code and parsing that in Javascript with JSON library
2. Appending raw HashMap object to MySQL.

The first approach did not work because when Java converts HashMap object to String, it strips off all quotation marks, which gives Javascript a confusion.

The second approach simply does not work.

Is there anyone with this similar experience who can give me a seamless solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by sending Gson object.